# Structure of the matrix to solve linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization

When I was watching the course on convex optimization by Stephen Boyd, at some point he says is to exploit structure when possible. One of the examples is the following matrix.

$$ {\bf A} =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  A & B \\
  C & D \\
 \end{pmatrix} $$

where $A$ is a big diagonal matrix, and the rest are dense block matrices. Such as the following picture, where the white part is all zeros.

[image: Picture of the structure of the matrix].

The linear system $\textbf{A}x=y$ is usually solved by solvers who are going to treat the matrix as a whole, in this case, the easy implementation is to have an sparse matrix to do work with an sparse solver. However, since there is a diagonal matrix, we might be able to do it faster. I was looking at the [Block Matrix Inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_inversion) to solve the linear system and implement it.

Extracting from wikipedia, we have the following formula:

$$
{\displaystyle \mathbf {P} ={\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf {A} &\mathbf {B} \\\\\mathbf {C} &\mathbf {D} \end{bmatrix}}^{-1}={\begin{bmatrix}\left(\mathbf {A} -\mathbf {BD} ^{-1}\mathbf {C} \right)^{-1}&-\left(\mathbf {A} -\mathbf {BD} ^{-1}\mathbf {C} \right)^{-1}\mathbf {BD} ^{-1}\\\\-\mathbf {D} ^{-1}\mathbf {C} \left(\mathbf {A} -\mathbf {BD} ^{-1}\mathbf {C} \right)^{-1}&\quad \mathbf {D} ^{-1}+\mathbf {D} ^{-1}\mathbf {C} \left(\mathbf {A} -\mathbf {BD} ^{-1}\mathbf {C} \right)^{-1}\mathbf {BD} ^{-1}\end{bmatrix}}.}
$$

Some parts of the matrix, such as $\left(\mathbf {A} -\mathbf {BD} ^{-1}\mathbf {C} \right)^{-1}$, seem to be non-optimal, since we are computing the inverse of a dense big matrix. Is there something I'm not seeing? I'm not sure how to tackle this problem.

Maybe I'm looking this problem from a wrong angle. Do you have any idea how to solve this linear system efficiently?

Comment: Don't you have an [arrowhead matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrowhead_matrix)?

Comment: You've written up the inverse in a way that makes use of $D^{-1}$. Given that $A$ is diagonal then (assuming no zeroes on its diagonal) you have $A$ as being invertible, so it would be better to swap their roles. Then you end up basically taking the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement). Instead of a large sparse matrix, you only have to invert a smaller dense matrix of the same size as $D$.

Comment: hi @RodrigodeAzevedo ,thanks for the comment, the arrowhead is all diagonal except one line and row. In my case this is not necessarily true. JaapScherphuis, maybe you are right, but I don't see it directly, I'll develop a bit further with that in mind and I'll keep you posted.

Comment: @silgon Then call it "block arrowhead"

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo ooohhhh, I see, thx =D

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I got a bit more time to think about it. Actually, it's really direct result with $x=A^{-1}(u-By)$ and $\left(D-CA^{-1}B\right)y=v-CA^{-1}u$ as you mentioned in the wiki page. I believe that it's analogous to what Rodrigo says. Anyway, thank you both!